# Why doesn't animSetInteger work properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a mobile 3d game, i've shared a picture from my character's movement script, if you look at it you can see there is an "anim.SetInteger" for each input but the "condition" doen't change to "1" for every direction. If you guys know what do i need to do that, pls let me know.

[MovementScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW1p0.png)
[MovementScript2 ("Else" part)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvf8.png)

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` statement only applies to your final `if` statement.  What's probably happening is that one of your first six `if` statements is true, so then your `Condition` animation parameter gets set to 1.  **But** since your final `if` statement if false, the `else` block also gets executed, so `Condition` gets set back to zero within the same game loop iteration.

Change all of your middle `if` statements to `else if`.  It should be like this:

```
if (/* condition 1 */)
{
   anim.SetInteger("Condition", 1);
   // transform = ...
}
else if (/* condition 2 */)
{
   anim.SetInteger("Condition", 1);
   // transform = ...
}
else if (/* condition 3 */)
{
   anim.SetInteger("Condition", 1);
   // transform = ...
}
else
{
   anim.SetInteger("Condition", 0);
   horizontal = 0;
   vertical = 0;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  The reason that your `ClampMagnitude` wasn't working is that  `Vector3.ClampMagnitude(Vector3.forward, moveSpeed)` will shrink `Vector3.forward` to `moveSpeed` if `moveSpeed` is less than the magnitude of `Vector3.forward`.  But if `moveSpeed` is greater than the magnitude of `Vector3.forward` (which is 1), then `ClampMagnitude` **will not** increase its length.  That's what multiplying works, but `ClampMagnitude` doesn't.